# Analog Audio Output resets to 0 automatically

Tags: raspbian, audio

I have a RP 4 and I am trying to get sound out of the minijack socket..
The GUI loudpseaker icon offers analog & HDMI. When I select Analog or HDMI, push the volume to max and close the tab, the loudspeaker icon drops to 0 automatically.

I have tried forcing the analog channel

```
sudo amixer cset numid=3 1
```

I have fiddled with all I can using the command
alsamixer

But whenever I quit out, the channels zero out.
I have tried the le above with the Alsamixer gui.

In :

```
sudo raspi-config
```

I have set the advance / audio settings to analog.

```
sudo raspi-config
[sudo] password for admin:
numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Volume'
; type=INTEGER,access=rw------,values=2,min=0,max=65536,step=1
: values=1,1
```

But still no sound.

My sound card is:

```
/proc/asound/cards
bcm2835_alsa
```

Any ideas would be most grateful.
Thank you

Comment: Analog sound works on a vanilla Raspbian. I suggest you start with a fresh install and get the sound working there. Then you can investigate what changes to the system break the sound functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the hdmi audio output, using

```
defaults.ctl.card 0
defaults.pcm.card 0
```

and it works. I presume this leaves me to deduce that analog circuit is defective. Not really sure what I can do.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: I have rolled back to

    defaults.ctl.card 0
    defaults.pcm.card 0 

and bought an hdmi to analog converter for 50 euros. At least the audio is in sync with the video and the sound is fine.

Comment: I have rolled back to

    defaults.ctl.card 0
    defaults.pcm.card 0 

and bought an hdmi to analog converter for 50 euros. At least the audio is in sync with the video and the sound is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the cards by configuring `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf`. Therefore, change it according to the value below.

From:

```
defaults.ctl.card 0
defaults.pcm.card 0
```

To:

```
defaults.ctl.card 1
defaults.pcm.card 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the config change. Sadly it has not made the sound come out of the Jack socket. I am starting to wonder if there is not a physical fault. I can't think of a way to check physical integrity.